# How to assign snap.val() to the global variable?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I want to assign `snap.val()` to `this.Productslike this.Products= snap.val();` but `this.Products` is undefined in that scope.

```
    Products: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
constructor(){

    } 

    ionViewDidLoad(){
      this.angularFire.database.list('/Products').$ref.orderByChild('uid')
     .equalTo('NW1Kq4WB7ReUz2BNknYWML9nF133').on('child_added', function(snap){
                console.log(snap.val().name);
              //this.Products= snap.val();
            });
      }
```

I tried the following code when snap is returned ,but I receive this message -- `No index defined for uid`:

```
snap.forEach(SnapShot=>{
console.log(SnapShot.val().name)
```

My Firebase database:

```
"Products" : {
    "-Kbx0i-TFeTyRbNZAZ_8" : {
      "category" : "1",
      "detail" : "xxxxx details",
      "name" : "xxxxx",
      "uid" : "NW1Kq4WB7ReUz2BNknYWML9nF133"
    }
```

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directly answer the question you asked, you can use an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
let query = this.angularFire.database.list('/Products').$ref.orderByChild('uid')
     .equalTo('NW1Kq4WB7ReUz2BNknYWML9nF133');
query.on('child_added', (snap) => this.Products= snap.val());
```

Or for ES5 compatibility, declare `this` as a variable:

```
let self = this;
let query = this.angularFire.database.list('/Products').$ref.orderByChild('uid')
     .equalTo('NW1Kq4WB7ReUz2BNknYWML9nF133');
query.on('child_added', function(snap) {
   self.Products= snap.val();
});
```

But in reality, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) and you don't want what you think you want here.

What you've done is reimplement the list yourself, and defeat the entire purpose of AngularFire2, which handles all this synchronization on your behalf.

Additionally, you've mis-used `child_added` by assigning each record you get back (you get an array of results, not exactly one) to `this.products`, when you probably wanted to set `this.products = []` and then use `this.products.push(snap.val())` for each child_added invocation.

So what you really want here, is to use AngularFire's [built-in queries](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/4-querying-lists.md) and avoid this entire mess :)

```
this.products = af.database.list('/Products', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'uid',
    equalTo: 'NW1Kq4WB7ReUz2BNknYWML9nF133' 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way:

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const firebaseConfig = {
    your firebaseConfig... 
};

let app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

let database = firebase.database();

export async function readFromFirebase(userId, key) {
  const ref = database.ref("users/" + userId + "/" + key);

  const snapshot = await ref.once("value");

  return snapshot.val();
}

async function main() {
  console.log(await readFromFirebase(109512127, "userName"));
}

main();
```